# Pie chart values don't equal 100%

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On the website "ArtFCity" there is a pie chart with values taken from a data table. However, the values inside the pie chart do not equal $100\%$. What is wrong with this math?

$55.59 + 31.1 + 2.19 + 2.63 + 1.83 + 1.51 + 1.64 + 0.23 + 0.16 + 0.26 + 0.27 = 97.41$

Is there a missing value somewhere?

Comment: Your sum is correct. Bad chart.

Comment: It would be useful to see the chart.

Comment: Okay, this appears to be the link: http://artfcity.com/2015/06/05/how-women-and-people-of-color-stack-up-in-journalism/

Comment: Note that the pie chart indicates it is *not* exactly the data listed - it had a $57$ on the white men piece, while the dataset has only $55.59$. This data is probably normalizing the original data to add up to 100. The original data probably includes lots of "not sure" data.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, there is a missing value somewhere. If they included everything, we would expect the total to be 100. Sometimes, due to truncation, we might get something like 99.9 or nearby, but that's not the case here.

It's not the first time [someone was wrong on the internet](https://xkcd.com/386/).

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely a missing term, because as figures are rounded to 2 sig. figs. after the decimal point, the maximum error is $\pm(0.01\cdot11)=\pm 0.11$. However, $|100-97.41|>0.11$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to 55.59 + 31.1 + 2.19 + 2.63 + 1.83 + 1.51 + 1.64 + 0.23 + 0.16 + 0.26+ 0.27 is definitely 97.41. The website may not have been able to get the exact values, as they stated in the subheading of the graph.

However, pie charts are always equivalent to 100%. There is nothing wrong with the math. Just a rounding miscalculation.